# External CSS stylesheet not linking

Tags: html, css, xhtml, external, stylesheet

First off, I would like to add that I have looked through many posts before this, none matching my exact situation.

Problem:

1. "Lounge.html" is the 'index' html file shown below
2. "test.css" is the external .css file I am trying to link to, also show below
3. "Lounge.html" and "test.css" are both in the same folder; the root folder
4. All "img" and "a" elements *are* in working order
5. When I run "Lounge.html" in either Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer, the style is not applied to my page.

I would appreciate some help with getting this external link working.

Regards,

AA

```css
h1, h2 {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: gray;
}
h1 {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
p {
font-family: sans-serif;
color: maroon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>Head First Lounge</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to the New and Improved Head First Lounge</h1>
    <p><img src="images/drinks.gif" alt="Drinks" /></p>
    <p>
      Join us any evening for refreshing 
      <a href="beverages/elixir.html">elixirs</a>, 
      conversation and maybe a game or two of 
      <em>Dance Dance Revolution</em>.  
      Wireless access is always provided;  
      BYOWS (Bring Your Own Web Server).
    </p>
    <h2>Directions</h2>
    <p>
      You'll find us right in the center 
      of downtown Webville.  If you need help finding
      us, check out our 
      <a href="about/directions.html">detailed directions</a>. 
      Come join us!
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"When I run "Lounge.html" in either Microsoft Edge, or Internet Explorer, the style is not applied to my page."_ - so it works in other browsers?

Comment: Have you tried to clear your browser cache?

Comment: Also try tracing the css using element inspector console.

Comment: Well, it obviously works in the snippet, so there may be no other course of action than to share a link to your website.

Comment: I have not tried it in any other browser other than IE and MS Edge, When tracing the css element, it finds the right directory. I am doing this locally, so there is no link to my "website".

Comment: Is this on the web? Are you able to access the stylesheet by yoursite.com/test.css?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the browsers.

For IE : If you are still getting the error, insert

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

in your `<head>` section and try loading it.

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

This may be the problem of browser cache. **Clear the cache** and check it again. Simple way to clear cache is add some radom string after adding ? to the url. Example

```
http://example.com/test.html?somerandomtext
```

Comment: Interestingly, the external stylesheet worked when I uploaded both files to a personal website I created to test my html...

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, if "fix" is what you would like to call it,  I simply uploaded both files (html, css) to a web hosting server. The 'index' html file was immediately affected by the external stylesheet, unlike my attempt at local methodology.